# Regex - maximum 30 chars with limitation

Tags: regex

I still didn't manage to find a solution for the problem that I have with my regex.

Case:

Input-

> Deutsche Gesellschaftsgeschichte

Expected output:

1. Group 1 - Deutsche
2. Group 2 - Gesellschaftsgeschichte

The reason is because both word together exceed 30 chars, so they are separated into two groups.

The maximum input can be up to 90 chars.

More examples of inputs and expected outputs:

Input -

> Fachlich geeignet, politisch unzuverlässig...

Output -

> 1. Fachlich geeignet, politisch
> 2. unzuverlässig...

Input -

> Textbuch zur Privatrechtsgeschichte der Neuzeit

Output -

> 1. Textbuch zur
> 2. Privatrechtsgeschichte der
> 3. Neuzeit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get what you want in up to 3 Groups, you can use this regex:

```
(\b.{1,30}(?=\b))(\b.{1,30}(?=\b))?(\b.{1,30}(?=\b))?
```

The regex starts with a `Word boundary`, then matches from `1 to 30` of `any` character, then it looks forward for a `Word boundary` (making sure we match and splits `Whole Words`).

This pattern is `repeated 3 times` (where the last 2 are optional).

Now you have your matches in 3 Groups, which you can access per index.